# Modyfying parent class attribute in __init__

Tags: python

I would like to build object oriented model for file/strings converter. 
I managed to solved the issue using functional approach but it just beggs for OOP.

Here is the case:

My input data to convert is a list of common dictionaries but with different values (dump from CSV file).

I need to update value of `data3` in class A which is hidden inside of a list (`fileHeader`) that is initialized within A's `__init__` method.

```
class Common(object)
    def __init__(self, c):  # for now c will be a dictionary that we iterate over in external loop
        self.c = c

    def printdata(self, obj): # method used for printing (writting to a file in future)
        print ''.join(obj)
```

```
 class A(Common):   # creates file header
    def __init__(self, c):  #c is a dict
        self.c = c
        __data1 = 'data1'
        self.__data2 =  'data2'
        self.data3 = 'data3'
        self.fileHeader = [__data1, __data2, self.__data3] # contains data3 value that i want to modify in Class B
```

```
class B(A):  # creates file footer, need to use modified fileHeader value
    def __init__(self, c):
        A.__init__(self, c)     # gives me access to self.fileHeader
        ## magically change fileHeader's value updateing data3##
        data4 = 'data4' 
        data5 = 'data5'
        ....
        self.fileFooter = [data4, ''.join(self.fileHeader), data5]  # refering fileHeader here gives me original 'data3' value
```

Actual behaviour is that i get:

`fileHeader = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']`

`fileFooter = ['data4','data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data5' ]`

desired behaviour is to get **modified** `data3='data3_modified'`:

`fileHeader - no changes`

`fileFooter = ['data4','data1', 'data2, 'data3_modified', 'data5' ]`

note that i've ignored ''.join() result for readability

Comment: Have you heard of `super`?

Comment: Have you tried `self.data3 = ...` ?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini `self.data3 = ..` changes its locally in class B scope, but what i want to do is to use modified attribute (fileHeader) of class A inside of class B (fileFooter) .

Comment: @Mrv: I think you are making some confusion between classes and instances of those classes. Can you provide the expected behavior/result?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini sure, assumnig that **fileHeader** looks like that `['data1', 'data2', 'data3']` i would like to have **fileFooter** like that `['data4', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3_modified', 'data5']` or even better including ''.join result : `['data4', 'data1data2data3_modified', 'data5']`

Comment: Perhaps I got it: you want to modify `data3` *and* you want `fileHeader` to be automatically updated whenever `data3` changes?

Comment: Can be, the issue is in updating `fileHeader's` value (`data3`). In class B i inherit `fileHeader` with orginal value, i need it to be modified so that `fileFooter` will receive correct value. Hope i am clear enough :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 `super` seems like a good idea, but how to use it this specific case? Even if I change via `super` value of `data3` still `fileHeader` used in creating `fileFooter` will refer to orginal value from class A.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes don't "belong" to a class in the hierarchy. They belong to the current object, which is an instance of B but inherits from A and Common; every attribute defined in code in those classes is *directly* available on A. This is the fundamental thing about subclassing.

So, you can just access `self.data3` in your `B.__init__` code, or anywhere else.

Comment: I was not precised i guess, accessing `self.data3` is not a problem, thats fine and can be changed any time. The problem is in accessing **self.fileHeader** which holds a data3 value inside. So when i do ` A.__init__(self, c) ` in class B i access now fileHeader with wrong value of `data3`. I want to change its value and use it in fileFooter with my modification. Ive described expected behaviour in comment above.